# How to remove a div element at a specific index using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I dynamically create a form. There is an <kbd>add line</kbd> button that adds a new line that includes a <kbd>delete line</kbd> button.

I originally wrote this in angular, and I was able to pass `"$index"` into the function to remove the specific line.
I am now rewriting my code in pure js, and my question is: How can I go about implementing this same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example for deleting elements by index as per your requirement can be found in this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ChaitanyaMunipalle/9z73rfjx/2/. I assume you will take care of adding lines & delete buttons dynamically. It contains only deletion.

As you have not given any code, I assumed the html would look like the below one:

```
<div id="lines">
    <div class="line-item">
        <input type="text" name="line-value"/> <button class="delete-line">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="line-item">
        <input type="text" name="line-value"/> <button class="delete-line">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="line-item">
        <input type="text" name="line-value"/> <button class="delete-line">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to add event listeners to delete buttons. And you have to use closure to save the index of the button clicked.

```
var deleteItem = function(index) {
    var divElements = document.getElementsByClassName("line-item");
    for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
    if (i == index) {
        divElements[i].parentNode.removeChild(divElements[i]);
        break;
    }
  }
};

var deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("delete-line");

for (var i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
    (function(index){
        deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
          deleteItem(index);
        }, false); 
    })(i);    
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your setup, but removing a div is just 
parentNode.removeChild(yourDiv)

If you only have the parentNode but know the index of the div you want to delete, then
parentNode.removeChild(parentNode.children[i])

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean way to remove element by index:

```
parent.removeChild(parent.childNodes[index]);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
`<div id="div1">
   <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
   <p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
<script>
   var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
   var child = document.getElementById("p1");
   parent.removeChild(child);
</script>`
```

This a example in jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/AlfonsoRamirez9/ttj1sLo5/

I hope help you :)